# showing a plane curve non-generic by exhibiting an even divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $G$ be a projective plane degree $2d$ curve with equation $AC-B^2$, with $A$, $B$, $C$ of degrees $\deg A=2d-4$, $\deg B=d$, $\deg C=4$. Then, for $d>2$, a dimension count shows that $G$ is not generic.
Note that $A$ cuts an even divisor on $G$, of degree $2d(2d-4)$.

Is it true that for a smooth projective plane degree $2d$ curve $X$, existence of a degree $2d-4$ curve $A$ of degree $2d-4$ cutting out an even divisor on $X$ implies that $X$ is not generic?

I can show this for $d=3$, by showing that in this case $X$ can be written as $AC-B^2$, as above; in general this isn't feasible, as $A$ can be singular, and it's not clear how to proceed.

Comment: In the first paragraph the degree of the divisor cut out by $C$ should be $8d$. You probably mean the divisor cut out by $A$.

Comment: oops, yes, thanks, indeed, I meant A there. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition that there is a degree $2d - 4$ curve cutting out on a plane curve $X$ of degree $2d$ an even divisor is equivalent to the existence of a point
$$
\alpha \in \operatorname{Pic}^0(X)
$$
of order 2 such that the divisor class
$$
(d-2)H + \alpha \in \operatorname{Pic}^{2d(d-2)}(X)\tag{*}
$$
is effective, where $H$ is the restriction to $G$ of the line class.
Since
$$
2d(d-2) < (2d - 1)(d-1) = g(X) - 1
$$
the plane curve $X$ is not generic.

EDIT. Let me show that for a general smooth plane curve $X$ with a non-trivial point $\alpha \in \operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$ of order 2 the divisor class $(*)$ is not effective. Since this condition is open (by semicontinuity of cohomology) and the moduli space of pairs $(X,\alpha)$ is connected, it is enough to find one pair $(X,\alpha)$ for which $(*)$ is not effective.

Consider a general symmetric matrix of size $d \times d$ with entries homogeneous polynomials of degree 2 in three variables. It gives a self dual exact sequence on $\mathbb{P}^2$
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus d} \to \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus d} \to \mathcal{L} \to 0,
$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle on a smooth plane curve $X \subset \mathbb{P}^2$. The self-duality of the matrix implies that $\mathcal{L}$ has the form
$$
\mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{O}(dH + \alpha)
$$
where $\alpha$ is a non-trivial point of order 2 on $X$. So, to check that $(*)$ is not effective in this case, we can just twist the above exact sequence by $\mathcal{O}(-2)$ and use the cohomology exact sequence.

Comment: How does the last inequality imply non-genericity? (I'm not very much at home with all the formultions of Riemann-Roch, etc).

Comment: For the line bundle $L$ corr. to $(d-2)H+\alpha$ Riemann inequality says $h^0(X,L)\geq 2d(d-2)-1+g(X)=-d$, which is basically the last inequality - but why does this imply non-genericity? (This is probably well-known, but I struggle to find a reference).

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: I added an explanation of non-genericity (with an example of a pair $(X,\alpha)$ for which $(*)$ is not effective).

Comment: OK, thanks, although I don't see an immediate connection with the inequality I was wondering about.

Comment: Is it known, for a generic plane curve, how big $m$ should be in the analogue to (*): $mH +\alpha\in Pic^{2dm}(X)$ for the class to be effective? Is it $m=2d-2$ (a guess from some paper by Hilbert from 1893) ?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: If already $m = d - 1$ one has $\deg(mH) = 2d(d-1) > g(X) - 1$, hence the class $mH + \alpha$ is effective.